Program not running with permission of the owner even though SUID is set
I have a program ./prog that is owned by root and has the SUID bit set.
Permission: -rwsr-sr-x 1 root
Then I check the EUID by geteuid() but when I run this (as a user), the output EUID is still my user id, rather than root.
What could be the problem?

Is it saved on a filesystem with the nosuid flag set? (Use mount | grep -w "$(df ./prog | awk '{print $1}')" and add its results to your question if you're not sure.)

@ChrisDavies Running that didn't return anything

Is it a script or a binary executable? The SUID bit doesn't work for scripts.

You're in the correct directory for ./prog to work? Make sure that if you invented ./prog for your question that you update it in the code I've given you too. it should have returned something - even if it was the entire list from running mount or an error message

What OS are you using? Linux? BSD? Mac? Cygwin? WSL? What distribution or version is it?

I'm using Ubuntu through ssh. I believe the environment is docker container. I can see the output of df ./prog | awk '{print $1}', but that directory is not among the output of mount. Also, ./prog is a binary executable produced by gcc.

Docker changes everything

@ChrisDavies sudo actually works fine for me

OK. I revert to my original question, "Is it [your program] saved on a filesystem with the nosuid flag set?"
